# Проверка на наличие и расположение символа в строке

Tags: c#

В общем, нужно как-то сделать проверку на наличие и расположение символов в строке.

К примеру, есть такая строка:

> Привет[]

P.S. [] - не массив, просто строка.

Нужно проверить нахождение символов "[]" и туда, к примеру, поставить 1.

Типа такого:

> Привет[1]

Как это сделать?

Строки могут быть любыми, хоть даже такими:

> Добрый день, как дела? Что я должен сегодня сделать? []

Comment: `string.Replace("[]", "[1]")` ?

Comment: Что-то не работает.  Строка: g = "Привет! Как дела?[]";   Replace:  g.Replace("[]", "[1]"); Выход: Привет! Как дела?[]

Comment: `g = g.Replace("[]", "[1]");`

Comment: @CrazyProgrammist: Вы не забыли, что функция Replace возвращает **новую** строку?

Comment: @tym32167, воу. Спасибо, работает.

Comment: @VladD, я вообще не знал о существовании такой функции :D

Comment: @tym32167: Почему не как ответ?

Comment: @VladD сэр, есть сэр! :D

Answer (score 3):

Чтобы произвести поиск и замену в строке, надо воспользоваться функцией [string.Replace()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

```
var g = "Привет! Как дела?[]";
g = g.Replace("[]", "[1]"); 
Console.WriteLine(g);
```

Вывод

```
Привет! Как дела?[1]
```